# Finding sentences between characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find sentences between pipe `|` and dot `.`, e.g.

> | This is one. This is two.

The regex pattern I use :

```
preg_match_all('/(:\s|\|+)(.*?)(\.|!|\?)/s', $file0, $matches);
```

So far I could not manage to capture both sentences.  The regex I use captures only the first sentence.

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: as it may seen from the regex, I am trying to find the sentences BETWEEN (: or |) AND (. or ! or ?)

Column or pipe indicates starting point for sentences.
The sentences might be:

```
: Sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence three. 
| Sentence one. Sentence two? 
| Sentence one. Sentence two! Sentence three?
```

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and just match on:

```
\s*[^.|]+\s*
```

This says to match any content not consisting of pipes or full stops, and it also trims optional whitespace before/after each sentence.

```
$input = "| This is one. This is two.";
preg_match_all('/\s*[^.|]+\s*/s', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  This is one
    [1] =>  This is two
)
```

Comment: It's simple but not my interpretation of what the OP is looking for. If `$input` is `"John loves Mary.| This is one. This is two."`, then it also matches `John loves Mary`, which is not *between a | and a .`.

Comment: I consider `John loves Mary` to in fact be a sentence in this case.

Comment: We agree it's a sentence but it is not between `|` and `.`. It comes before the pipe character.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job:

```
$str = '| This is one. This is two.';
preg_match_all('/(?:\s|\|)+(.*?)(?=[.!?])/', $str, $m);
print_r($m)
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => | This is one
            [1] =>  This is two
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is one
            [1] => This is two
        )

)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/2hlNDB/1)

Comment: You probably only want to print the second array element, and also you may want to add some non capturing groups to your regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It's up to OP to choose what they want to keep, I've printed the whole match to show how it captures the strings. A non capture group is already in place.

Comment: On input `John loves Mary.  | This is one. This is two.`, you also match `loves Mary`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make use of `\G` to get iterative matches asserting the position at the end of the previous match and capture the values in a capturing group matching a dot and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars after.

```
(?:\|\h*|\G(?!^))([^.\r\n]+)\.\h*
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\|\h*` Match `|` and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture group 1
  `- [^.\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char other than `.` or a newline
- `)` Close group
- `\.\h*` Match 1 `.` and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fbazra/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/iL62c)

For example

```
$re = '/(?:\|\h*|\G(?!^))([^.\r\n]+)\.\h*/';
$str = '| This is one. This is two.
John loves Mary.| This is one. This is two.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => | This is one. 
            [1] => This is one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is two
            [1] => This is tw
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, find everything between `|` and `.` and then split:

```
$input = "John loves Mary. | This is one. This is two. | Sentence 1. Sentence 2.";
preg_match_all('/\|\s*([^|]+)\./', $input, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
        print_r(preg_split('/\.\s*/', $match));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is one
    [1] => This is two
)
Array
(
    [0] => Sentence 1
    [1] => Sentence 2
)
```

Comment: `This is two.` and `Sentence 2.` are not between `|` and `.`

Comment: `|` This is one. This is two`.` I have highlighted the characters I believe that qualifies. The OP wants sentence**s** (multiple) between these two characters and complained that he could not capture both sentences.

Comment: Conclusion there are more than 1 interpretation of the question => need clarification from OP.